# After an earlier US overstay, I was denied entry to the US; can this be reversed?

Tags: usa, overstaying, denial-of-entry

In 2014, I entered the US in January as a tourist had the I94 valid until July; I overstayed (until December) for 5 months more than I was allowed. I tried to return this week, almost 4 years later, got denied entry and sent back to Brazil the next day. Is there any way to reverse the denial? What could I do to return legally, after I violated the terms on my earlier visa?

Comment: "violating a law" is the *definition* of committing a crime...

Comment: I think your only option is to invent and build a time machine and use it to go back in time and *not* overstay. And just to reiterate: Overstaying *is* a crime.

Comment: You cannot reverse the denial. The USA does not want you back, and you have yourself to blame. You do not have a bar to entry since your overstay was was less than six months. That said being issued a visa is a privilege, not a right and they have decided to subsequently deny you the privilege. Your chances of ever entering the USA on a nonimmigrant visa in the future are slim at best but particularly nonexistent under this administration.

Comment: Overstaying a visa in the USA is not a crime, it is a civil offense. Crimes are criminal offenses, let’s get that straight. Some people behave here like overstaying a visa is similar to committing a homicide. Let’s get real and cut out the pontificating.

Comment: @Dan You may be eligible to apply for a Waiver of Inadmissibility https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1769/~/waiver-of-inadmissibility---applying-for-advance-permission-to-enter-the-u.s.

Comment: This site's usual advice in this situation is to apply for a formal visa, even if you come from a country usually eligible for the Visa Waiver Program. Answer honestly on the application that you overstayed in the past. You will have to show stronger-than-average reasons to return on time, given a second chance. Your application will probably be rejected, but it saves you the cost of airfare and refused entry.

Comment: Your best chance is a major change in your circumstances that makes another overstay very unlikely. The combination of a good job, paying much more than you could get working underground in the US, and a stable home might possibly do it.

Comment: @Henrik: "And just to reiterate: Overstaying is a crime." Wrong. Overstaying in the US is NOT a crime. Something must be specifically defined as a crime in the law for it to be a crime. No federal law defines overstaying as a crime. No law provides for any fine or jail time for overstay.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: ""violating a law" is the definition of committing a crime..." Wrong. Many legal violations are NOT crimes.

Comment: @user102008 Feel free to take it up on English.SE, but [according to the dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Crime), you're wrong. That being said, lying to an immigration officer or on a visa application *is* a crime. (18 U.S.C. § 1001)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Actually, the #1 definition on there agrees with me. There needs to be a punishment as the result of a conviction. You cannot be prosecuted for or convicted of overstay in criminal court, because it is not a criminal offense. There is no criminal "punishment" for it.

Comment: HI new user @Dan.   It sounds like your only hope is to carefully apply for a "full" visa at your leisure, and hope it works.   (Ever since us Europeans went to the Americas, killed off all the natives, and started drawing funny lines on the maps, it's often *really hard* to travel around there.)

Comment: @Traveller it's not clear that Dan is inadmissible.  If Dan is not inadmissible, a waiver of inadmissibility will not help.  Dan: on what grounds were you refused entry?  Were you allowed to withdraw your application for admission, or were you removed?  The paperwork that you should have received from the CBP officers should help answer those questions.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no avenue for appeal or option to "reverse" a decision. The fact is, you overstayed; you cannot change that. Your only option is to apply for a new visa, demonstrating very strong ties to your home country, and hope that they approve it. If they don't, there is nothing else you can do.

Comment: I was just curious Greg, in this situation, let's say the person P actually MARRIED a USA woman, W.  (So, let's say W happened to be working in Brazil for two years as a manager at a corporation, P was also a manager at the corporation, they meet, fall in love, get married (in Brazil, say), and have a child.)  Even in that case,  would P typically be allowed entry to the USA??

Comment: @Fattie: Sorry, I don't know. In that case I would strongly suggest "consult an immigration lawyer". :)

Comment: And the immigration lawyer would likely say (given the current political climate): “have a nice life in Brazil raising your family.”

Comment: @Fattie: If they are applying for a nonimmigrant visa (e.g. a visitor visa), they might continued to be denied for the same reason they are being denied now (i.e. failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent). If they are applying for an immigrant visa, i.e. to immigrate to the US, then they would not be denied for immigrant intent; they should not have any problems getting an immigrant visa unless there is a ban, and nothing that has been mentioned so far indicates that she has a ban (she would have to accrue 180 days of unlawful presence before leaving to trigger a 3-year ban).